# Android GridView causing lagg

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gridview

I am currently working on a file sharing application. I created a GridView, where I would like to list the already downloaded files with a thumbnail. To achieve this, I use a custom adapter. It loads fine, everything is visible, seems perfect.

And the trick is the following: after the view is loaded, the getView method of my custom adapter is called on position 0 so many times, that it causes massive laggs, with about 12% CPU usage on my Xperia XZ Premium.

I already read answers about laggs in GridView, but in those cases it was caused by scrolling. In my case, no scroll is needed, currently there is only 1 item in the GridView, but it is still struggling.

While lagging, it also spams a message. This message can disappear, if I add the following line of code to my TextViews:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

But this attribute is deprecated and doesn't solves the issue, only the message disappears.

The lagg is not present, when the view is empty.

The getView method of my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem==null){
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.downloaded_grid_item, parent, false);
    }

    final Downloaded current = getItem(position);

    final ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_grid_item_thumb);
    final TextView name = (TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_grid_item_name);
    final TextView subtext = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_grid_item_subtext);

    thumbnail.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int width = thumbnail.getMeasuredWidth();
            thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));
            return true;
        }
    });

    listItem.setTag(position);
    thumbnail.setTag(position);
    name.setTag(position);
    subtext.setTag(position);

    name.setText(current.getName());
    subtext.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(current.getTime())));
    thumbnail.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(current.getPath()), 400, 400));

    return listItem;
}
```

The GridView:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/downloaded_grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

The custom layout of the items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/downloaded_grid_item"
android:background="@drawable/downloaded_grid_item_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/downloaded_grid_item_thumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/downloaded_grid_item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    tools:text="name"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/downloaded_grid_item_subtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    tools:text="download date"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the message, spammed by the device:

```
W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code in an emulator (Android 7), I did not manage to get the message about the maxLineHeight but I can confirm that there was no end of `getView()` being called.

The reason for this behavior is that each time `getView()` is executed you add a new `OnPreDrawListener` without ever removing it. Changing the `ImageView`'s height forces a recalculation of how it is to be drawn. This causes the whole `GridView` to go through a new layout pass (measure - draw - layout). So `getView()` is called again (normally at least twice for position 0). Because you never remove a `OnPreDrawListener` they all will fire once more, only causing more and more work for the CPU without actually changing the value for the `ImageView`'s height.

You need to remove the Listeners you add to a `ViewTreeObserver` as soon as you obtained the desired information. So you need to write

```
thumbnail.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        thumbnail.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        int width = thumbnail.getMeasuredWidth();
        thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually solved my problem. However the messages are still present, but not spammed.

Comment: @Dávid Besenyei - the message is only a warning, so it may never be a problem for your app. Are you even using a StaticLayout anywhere? I could only see your GridView which I placed into a LinearLayout for testing. And like I said, I don't see the message in my setup. The message may come from some component which is not part of your Activity/ Fragment (e.g. status bar). It may only appear on certain devices or when using certain build tools versions. (cont)

Comment: (cont)My advice is: if your app is working simply ignore the warning. If you run into problems, ask a new question with enough code to reproduce the error and mention which build tools version your are using and (ideally) which emulator(s) will show the problematic behavior. One other thing you could consider even now to improve performance: resizing the ImageView triggers a layout pass. Changing the padding of the ImageView will only cause the ImageView to be redrawn. So maybe you could work with an ImageView at maximum size and modify the padding to achieve a  scale animation

Comment: my app works perfectly now. I do not use any StaticLayout, I still do not know where this message comes from and it is only shown when the GridView is inflated. I was also ignoring it, since when my main problem has been solved. Regarding your other advice, I will consider it, thank you very much for your efforts.